# azure function python sync/async execution

Tags: python, logging, azure-functions

I currently test a simple setup to get a better understanding of loging in azure functions:

main file:

```
# function_app.py
import azure.functions as func
import logging

app = func.FunctionApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)
from submodule import subfntest

@app.route(route="fntest")
def fntest(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    
    logging.info('main_start')
    subfntest()
    logging.info('main_end')

    return func.HttpResponse(
             "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.",
             status_code=200
        )
```

submodule file:

```
#submodule/subfntest
import logging

def subfntest()->None:
    logging.info("subfntest")
```

When calling the function, I get the following log:

```
2023-07-17 12:37:20.097 Executing 'Functions.fntest' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=2c45312c-1d4e-4271-bf74-8439efdec03d)
2023-07-17 12:37:20.119 main_start Information
2023-07-17 12:37:20.121 main_end Information
2023-07-17 12:37:20.123 subfntest Information
2023-07-17 12:37:20.139 Executed 'Functions.fntest' (Succeeded, Id=2c45312c-1d4e-4271-bf74-8439efdec03d, Duration=42ms) Information
```

Why is the subfntest logging line executed after main_end and how do I force a synchronous execution?

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes to your code and got the exact output.

**Code:**

**function_app.py:**

```py
import azure.functions as func
import logging
from submodule.subfntest import subfntest

app = func.FunctionApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)

@app.route(route="fntest")
async def fntest(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('main_start')
    await subfntest()  # Wait for subfntest to complete before moving on
    logging.info('main_end')

    return func.HttpResponse(
        "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.",
        status_code=200
    )
```

**subfntest.py:**

```py
import logging

async def subfntest() -> None:
    logging.info("subfntest")
```

**requiremets.txt:**

```py
azure-functions
```

**Output:**

It runs successfully and gives the correct output as below,

[image]

With above **URL**, I got the output at browser as below,

[image]

Comment: I updated my code accordingly to async. I received mixed results.

most of the time I get: start > subfn > end. 

But I also receive startend without subfn as well as subfn > start > end and even subfn > end > start. 

Could you rerun your example and confirm this?